# Can I name an array with a variable in java?

Tags: java, arrays

for example I want to do this:

```
String[] arraynames = new String[2];
arraynames[0] = "fruits";
arraynames[1] = "cars";
```

and now I don't know how to do this

```
String[] arraynames[0] = new String[100]; // ??????
```

so that I create a String array called fruits with 100 cells...
I know this doesn't work but is there someway to do this?

Comment: are you saying you want an array of arrays or just an array named fruits?

Comment: He wants to store some strings in an Array, and then use the data of the array and name variables after that. Something which AFAIK cannot happen

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use an `HashMap`

Example:

```
HashMap<String,String[]> arraynames = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
arraynames.put("fruits", new String[1000]);

// then simply access it with
arraynames.get("fruits")[0] = "fruit 1";
```

However, may I suggest you replace arrays with `ArrayList` ?

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> arraynames = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
arraynames.put("fruits", new ArrayList<String>());

// then simply access it with
arraynames.get("fruits").add("fruit 1");
```

** **EDIT** **

To have an array of `float` values instead of strings

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<Float>> arraynames = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Float>>();
arraynames.put("fruits", new ArrayList<Float>());

// then simply access it with
arraynames.get("fruits").add(3.1415f);
```

Comment: I was going to post the exact same thing!

Comment: Right on. Based on further clarification this seems like what OP need (assuming I understood it right).

Comment: Thank you! I think this works! But can I do this with ArrayList of floats instead of Strings? I get an unexpected type error...

Answer (score 1):

So, you are looking for a doubly indexed array?

Something like:

```
String[][] arraynames = String[2][100];
```

You have created an array of 2 arrays that contain 100 String elements each in this case.

Comment: Yes, but I want to actually name the arrays with different names!

Comment: If that is the case you should use an ArrayList of 2 different types of Fruits objects. See Stacker's response.

Comment: As @CoolBeans mentions, yes - ArrayList is probably what you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get you right, you could something like this:

```
ArrayList arraynames = new ArrayList();

arraynames.add("fruits"); 
arraynames.add("cars");

arraynames.set(0, new ArrayList(100) );
```

Comment: OP wants to use Arrays sound like.

Comment: @CoolBeans: apparently he doesn't know what he really wants himself.

Comment: I will try this! This seems like what I need!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite clear on the second line of code here. You said you are trying to create a string array named fruits. This should suffice if I understood this right.

```
String [] fruits = new String[100];
```

Comment: I know this... The thing is I want to take the names of the arrays from another array, and they are like 100 of them...

Comment: I am not sure about taking names of arrays from another array. However, if you follow Yanick Rochon's approach, you can use the array name as the key in the Map and then the array itself is the value that you store data in.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a bi-dimensional array like this:

```
String[][] myData = new String[2][100];
```

now myData is an array with 2 elements, both of them are arrays of "100 cells", then you can use these 2 arrays as follows:

```
String[] fruits = myData[0];
String[] cars = myData[1];
fruits[0] = "peach";
cars[0] = "mustang";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library:

```
ListMultimap<String,String> mappedItems = ArrayListMultimap.create();
mappedItems.put("Fruits","Apple");
mappedItems.put("Fruits","Orange");
mappedItems.put("Fruits","Banana");
mappedItems.put("Cars", "BMW");
mappedItems.put("Cars","Ferrari");
System.out.println(mappedItems);
```

Output:

> {Cars=[BMW, Ferrari], Fruits=[Apple, Orange, Banana]}

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following :

```
String[][] arraynames = String[2][100];
Map<String, String[]> namesMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
List<List<String>> names = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>()>>();
```